# Django UpdateView: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: username

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django application containing a basic Profile model which extends the User model using the OneToOneField

```python
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

And this is the url pattern for /updateProfile

```python
path('updateProfile/<pk>', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
```

which is being called from the navigation bar of the website as follows:

```jinja
<a href="{% url 'update_profile' request.user %}">UpdateProfile</a>
```

I have utilised the ModelForm class in forms.py as follows:

```python
class update_profile_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('phone_number', 'profile_picture')
```

And in Views.py the following UpdateView class-based view is invoked:

```python
@method_decorator(login_required, 'dispatch')
class UpdateProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    form_class = update_profile_form
    template_name = 'update_profile.html'

    # this is where the error occurs
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

My urls.py file contains following patterns:

```python
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='Login/home.html'), name='home'),
    path('home/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='Login/home.html'), name='home'),
    path('updateProfile/<pk>', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
]
```

I am unable to determine what combination of user field to use above to render the form in the update_profile.html template.

Comment: you are using updateview, Why you need query_set there? you can remove that. And also change your link to `<a href="{% url 'update_profile' request.user.pk %}">UpdateProfile</a>`

Comment: I tried your solution, the page 404 error occurs. However i can access my template by altering the url from 127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/updateProfile/5 to 127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/updateProfile/1

Answer (score 1):

change this line in html

```
<a href="{% url 'update_profile' request.user %}">UpdateProfile</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'update_profile' request.user.id %}">UpdateProfile</a>
```

as `request.user returns user object`, but the `url` has `pk` which is needs an `int` field

Comment: Ok I tried your solution, it returns page 404 not found and the url is also incorrect i.e http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/updateProfile/5 inplace of http://127.0.0.1:8000/venter/updateProfile/1

Comment: yeah it will because, you app has a app_name i guess? you need to put it infront of the url in the template. if you cant understand, show the main urls and app urls file

Comment: also if I use Profile.objects.get inplace of Profile.objects.filter it throws an error: 'Profile' model has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: show the urls else how else i can say what is wrong, and if get gives you error keep the filter

Comment: this is the url pattern: path('updateProfile/<pk>', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),

Comment: cant you post the full urls file?

Answer (score 0):

This is return a object so that problem arise

```
return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Chnage this to

```
return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class UpdateProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = '/add login link/'
    redirect_field_name = 'add login field'
    model = Profile
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    form_class = update_profile_form
    template_name = 'update_profile.html'

   # add post function if you have
```

In the html,

```
<a href="{% url 'update_profile' profile.user.pk %}">UpdateProfile</a>
```

In the url,

```
path('updateProfile/<int:pk>/', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
```

Comment: it throws Reverse for 'update_profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. Also, note in views.py, the queryset()  contains: return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

Comment: You can change `profile.user.pk` to `user.pk` or `request.user.pk`, it depends where your html link is in your template. And you are not going to use queryset in updateview. So you don't need to add queryset there unless you are retriving a lot of users i.e. ListView. Adding to that, you can add get and post function instead using updateview.

Comment: Ok, tried it, throws a page 404 error, simply because the url link is 127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/updateProfile/5 to 127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/updateProfile/1... what do I do about this?

Comment: I did not get it? Is it 404 page when you change the pk from 5 to 1 manually in your url and that user does not exists?

Comment: when pk is 5, I encounter 404, but when I manually change it to id=1 in the url, the template is successfully rendered